# what is the meaning of = () -> in java?

Tags: java, operator-keyword

When I read about java concurrent I got following code sample

```
Runnable task = () -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Hello " + threadName);
        };

        task.run();
```

I've rarely seen = () -> operator, what is the meaning of this?

Comment: Yeah, its a lambda expression. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_lambda_expressions.htm, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/lambda-expressions-java-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`() -> {` is the opening of a no argument [lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and the `};` is the end of the expression.